# How to do a circle rotation(like flip a coin) transition in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-vue

The scenario is I placed a circle in a page, when I tap it, it will rotate 180deg, revolve around x or y axis, show different content for frontside and backside. Since `backface-visibility` is not supported in nativescript, I have no clue how to implement it, if u have any idea please let me know, thanks!

Comment: I don't think we have any plugin to support flip animation, you will have to do this natively. Refer [UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptiontransitionflipfromleft) on iOS / [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) on Android.

Comment: Would something like this (https://nativescripting.com/posts/cardflip-animation-in-nativescript) work for your use case?

Comment: @WilliamJuan thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.